# Unity and iOS: line inside an "if" always running, no matter the condition

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine

I have been dealing with this odd issue for a couple of days and I am really out of ideas.

I am programming in Unity for iOS. Here is the troubled fragment of code:

```
if (!aux.IsDownloaded())
{
    aux.restoreTransaction();
    aux.DownloadItem();
}
```

The really strange issue is that aux.DownloadItem() is always executed. It doesn't matter if the condition is true or false. If the condition is true, it shouldn't go inside the 'if', but it does! It just skip the first line (restoreTransaction) and runs the second one (DownloadItem). If the condition is false, it just runs normally.

I have tried several things in order to discover something more:

- If I comment the DownloadItem line, the debugger shows that it runs the restoreTransaction line no matter the value of the condition, but it is really running the DownloadItem, since the downloading takes place.
- If I replace the restoreTransaction line with any other expression (in my case, 15 lines of Debug.Log("ARGGG")), it just skip all of them and run the DownloadItem line.

I am really lost. I thought that it could be a data corruption, so I deleted the Library folder in my Unity project and cleared Monodevelop cache, but it keeps doing this weird thing.

I don't know what else to try. Any ideas would be welcome, please just drop any guess no matter how stupid it sounds in your heads, since I am really out of ideas, and at least I would like to keep trying.

EDIT: After some more test, there is clearly a difference between what the device is running and what I am debugging in monodevelop. Maybe a an issue from Unity 3D generating the xCode project?

This is by far the weirdest thing I have ever found.

Kind regards,

Aernarion

Comment: Are you debugging in the release mode?

Comment: No, Monodevelop is in Debug mode. Unity has also the "Development build" ticked.

Comment: Make the `aux.IsDownloaded()` into a variable, and put that into your debugger. Does that always stay on true?

Comment: I already did, I forgot to mention. It has always the right value. I also modified the DownloadItem function to accept a boolean as a parameter and passed that var. I guessed: "Ok, you are going inside, fine, I will check it there". In that moment I couldn't go inside the function anymore while debugging, even if I pressed the "step inside" button. It just kept running the download.

Comment: Just to be sure, please check `Project -> Properties -> Build -> Optimize Code`. Make sure it's disabled.

Comment: I couldn't find this option neither Unity3D, nor MonoDevelop. Could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: [How to: Modify Project Properties and Configuration Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z15yzzew.aspx)

Comment: Sorry, Mihai. I am not running Visual Studio, but MonoDevelop.

Comment: You're right. I haven't used that. From another thread: _Under the Project Options dialog, in the tree view on the left, navigate to Build / Compiler. There should be a checkbox on the right called "Enable optimizations", make sure it's off_.

Comment: Please, understand that I am using Unity3D. Monodevelop is just the editor, so I really think that it has nothing to do with it. I guess that it has to be a Unity3D problem or an xCode problem. Don't you think so?

Comment: I haven't used Monodevelop, but I'm pretty sure you also modify (either manually or by selecting new -> project) the way your solution builds by using the IDE. I've seen this kind of behavior on embedded systems, where everything is optimized. The code would enter on the else branch, and you would think "phew, that went well", but the next stop was on the if branch, and you would go "what the f...". You can try my suggestion or you can ignore it. I really don't know if that would solve your problem.

Comment: I never said that I wan's trying it! I tried it. I disabled the checkbox and saved the file. I went back to Unity and generated the xCode project, but nothing changed. As I stated above, there must be a difference between what I am debugging and what the device is running...

Comment: try deleting the app from the device, clean (if that is possible in unity), then rerun. at least Xcode is not updating the full app, but only changes on re-compile. and sometimes it just fails in seeing all changes

Answer (score 0):

Welcome,

(I can't write comment, because of my reputation, so if this not helps just delete answer)

It's not a real solution, but as you wrote:

> just drop any guess no matter how stupid it sounds in your heads

What about changing the last line? You tried to fill the code with junk ABOVE the problematic part. It seems if the statement is true, then runs the last line... If I'm right, then you can insert a new line AFTER, like `Debug.Log("WEIRDPROBLEM")`.

Hope it helps, and sorry for bad eng and "not to comment",

RAPTOR

Comment: Ok. I tried this.I added Debug.Log("") lines before and after the DownloadItem line. It now went to the last Debug.Log line instead the DownloadItem line, but it started the download anyway. There is clearly a difference between what the ios device is running and what I am debugging in monodevelop.

Comment: In this case... I have no idea :( Try to make a variable for IsDownloaded, and change the `if` statement to that variables value... or just change the code-snippet location in code, or I don't know... i never faced with this problem before. You can delete this "answer", as you like. :)

Comment: I also tried that. The variable is consistent and its value correct, but it keeps entering the if statement. O_o'

Comment: then start a brand new solution and copy-paste the code, it sounds mad, but sometimes it just works :D

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's just an issue with a debugger and your code is fine. You can make sure of it by logging the result of aux.IsDownloaded(). Something like:

```
bool downloaded = aux.IsDownloaded();
Debug.Log(downloaded);
if (downloaded) {
    ...
}
```

If correct value is logged and your debugger is stepping in the wrong lines, then either you're hitting a corner case in the debugger, or debugger meta data for the assembly is out of sync for some reason.

Comment: I already tried this. The value is correctly stored, but it keeps running the wrong line. Assuming that the problem is one of the two you are suggesting, how can I solve such a situation?